# Not able to open react-bootstrap modal from child component using react hooks to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to trigger my react-bootstrap modal which is in the parent component from a button inside the child component. To achieve this, I am passing the `handleShow` function into the child component as props but this doesn't seem to be working. The modal doesn't open up on clicking the button and there are no errors on the browser console.

Parent Component:

**OnboardPage.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'

import { PersonalDetails } from './personalDetails'
import { EmailVerification } from './emailVerification'
import { OnboardForm } from './form'
import { FAQs } from './faq'
import { LeftCol, RightCol, FormContainer } from './styles'
import './styles.css'
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const OnboardPage = props => {
    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true); 

    return (
        <Row>
            <LeftCol md={8}>
                <PersonalDetails parentShowFn={handleShow}/>
                <OnboardForm />
            </LeftCol>
            <RightCol md={4}>
                <EmailVerification />
                <FAQs />
            </RightCol>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} className="editModal">
                <FormContainer>
                    <Modal.Header className="editModalHeader">
                      <Modal.Title>Edit Personal Details</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                   
                        <Form>
                          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicName">
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Name" className="formInput"/>
                          </Form.Group>

                          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Email ID" className="formInput"/>
                          </Form.Group>

                          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPhoneNumber">
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" className="formInput"/>
                          </Form.Group>
                          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicName">
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Country you will work in" className="formInput"/>
                          </Form.Group>
                          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="submitBtn">
                            Save details
                          </Button>
                        </Form>
                    
                </Modal.Body>
                </FormContainer>
            </Modal>
        </Row>
    )
}

export default OnboardPage
```

Child Component:

**PersonalDetails.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

import { colors } from '../../../../res'
import { TitleText, CommonText, SubHeadingText } from '../../../commons/freelancer/texts'
import { Container, TitleRow, DetailsRow, DetailsItem, EditBtn } from './personalDetailsStyles'
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
// import EditDetailsModal from './EditDetailsModal'

const PersonalDetails = ({parentShowFn}) => {

    return (

        <Container>
        <TitleRow>
            <TitleText>Personal Details</TitleText>
            <EditBtn onClick={() => parentShowFn()}>Edit</EditBtn>
        </TitleRow>
    </Container>
    )

}
    
export default PersonalDetails
```

Can't seem to trace why this isn't working.

Comment: Can't see a reason. Can you create a codesandbox which reproduce the issue?

Comment: I also can't see why this doesn't work - but come on, this is debugging 101. Use React devtools, or the debugger - or even just console.log statements if you can't use that for some reason - to figure out more precisely *what* the issue is. Is the `Modal` component getting its `show` prop set to `true`? Is the `handleShow` in the parent getting called? If not, what is? Going down this route won't necessarily let you solve the problem but will at least narrow down what it is - then you can ask a more focused question if you still need help.

Comment: I've tried in stackblitz everything seems fine for me too https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nu7nlr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the styled component of `<EditBtn>` was missing {...props}. It hence wasn't passing the onClick prop to the click listener. Thanks for your replies.